# Why is my .NET WEB API on IIS listing physical files and not my Website

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a .NET (not core) WEB API.
When I run it on mode debug in Visual Studio, and try to call the GET method of my API via Browser or Postman, it works fine!

[image: Running in Mode debug via Visual Studio, it works!]

But I am trying to publish it on my local IIS.
I published it via Visual Studio on a local folder. Created a website on IIS and made it point to the local folder.

[image: My website on IIS]

When I try to open it on Browser, it just lists the files that are in the local folder. It doesnt execute my webAPI correctly.

[image]

Any insight on that?

[image: The local files]

Comment: when I see web.config and global.asax and asp.net-web-api I really start to doubt anything you stated in the above... that being said - seems like IIS is just serving what you want it to serve... have you tried any URL after that, like /home/index (or something you actually want to serve?)

Comment: @riffnl Yeah, I tried to acess the GET method in the API URL, like I do on postman when executing in Visual Studio. Looks like its trying to find the files instead of routing, as the SS: https://imgur.com/a/AYhwcyL

Comment: IIS doesn't look like it's actually hosting an app - it looks like you're missing quite a few options. Do you have the .NET 5 hosting installed? (and on that note.. on .NET 5 when missing a page not getting a 404 could be an option) - but still is it really a NET5-API? The whole structure you show in the images looks like .NET Framework

Comment: @riffnl its a 4.7.2 App. Did I say its NET5 or something? sorry if I did lol

Comment: @riffnl I just enabled all IIS options on Windows App resources and it worked! Might find wich one is later...atm I will just leave it this way lol thx for help

Comment: my bad - but that aside, you're really missing options in your IIS view. Have you installed the IIS installer (like this https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net472 ) on your server?

Comment: that is a really bad idea for production servers, but for local testing it could do the trick

Comment: @riffnl yeah just made a comment about that! thx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238880/discussion-between-riffnl-and-marcel-james).